# Why is my custom arduino library not working?

Tags: arduino, libraries

I am making a custom arduino library for my "game console". Anyway, when I use the library in my main file, it gives me this error:

Invalid library found in /Users/nikos/Documents/Arduino/libraries/LEDConsole: no headers files (.h) found in /Users/nikos/Documents/Arduino/libraries/LEDConsole

To make this library I followed the official library making guide(https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/libraryTutorial), but it doesn't tell me anything that could help me. I searched around but I couldn't find anything that helps.

Here is the code:

Main file:

```
#include <LEDConsole.h>


LEDConsole console();

void setup() {

}

void loop() {
  console.display();
}
```

Header(LEDConsole.h):

```
#ifndef KEYPAD_H
#define KEYPAD_H

class LEDConsole
{
    public:
        LEDConsole();
        void setPixel(byte x, byte y, byte v);
        void display();
    private:
    byte img[];
};

#endif
```

LEDConsole.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LEDConsole.h"

LEDConsole::LEDConsole() {
    for(int i = 39; i < 54; i += 2) {
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < 10; i ++) {
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    }
    img[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
}

void LEDConsole::setPixel(byte x, byte y, byte v) {

    bitWrite(img[y], 7 - x, v);

}

void LEDConsole::display() {

    for(int y = 0; y < 8; y ++) {
        int yPin = 53 - y * 2;
        digitalWrite(yPin, HIGH);
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x ++) {
            int xPin = 2 + x;
            bool show = bitRead(img[y], 7 -x);

            if(show) digitalWrite(xPin, 128);
            else digitalWrite(xPin, 0);
        }
        for(int i = 2; i < 10; i ++) {
            digitalWrite(i, 0);
        }
        digitalWrite(yPin, LOW);

    }
}
```

Comment: how are the files placed in the library folder?

Comment: the tutorial is ok. So if you followed it correctly you should have no errors. the error message is about a file missing. not about your code. so instead of code, please provide info on the files and folders you created

Comment: In my libraries folder, I have a directory named "LEDConsole". Inside of it, I have another folder called "src". Inside that folder are both the header and cpp file

Comment: Have you tried to include it from the IDE from Sketch -> Include Library. Maybe its an IDE issue?